# Exported Google+ photos, how do I Merge JPG and Json for a full folder?

Tags: exiftool

I have a full back-up of my Google Photo pictures from google Archive. 
This comes in folders with 2 type of files in it. *.jpg and *.Json, *.json has the metadata.

Now i found this article ([Exported Google+ photos, how do I convert JSON data into EXIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156766/exported-google-photos-how-do-i-convert-json-data-into-exif/56477127#56477127)) but it's for a single file and works.

```
exiftool -json=picture.json picture.jpg
```

Somebody know how i can do this for full folders? Folders have multiple files Img_1234.jpg.json and img_1234.jpg Etc

[Exported Google+ photos, how do I convert JSON data into EXIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156766/exported-google-photos-how-do-i-convert-json-data-into-exif/56477127#56477127)

exiftool -json=picture.json picture.jpg

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914024/3525475).  But part of the problem is that the data names in the json file don't necessarily match up with the names of image metadata tags.  So run `exiftool -s` on the json file to get the current names (since Google is constantly changing how it names the data) and then declare where you want the data to go.

Comment: This post answers perfectly your request!
<https://stackoverflow.com/a/42914024/12299882>